# Reverse Engineering HTTP API between iOS device and wifi device on same network

Tags: api, http, postman, reverse-engineering, fiddler

I have a device that connects wirelessly to my network. This deivce has a dedicated iOS app but it hasnt been updated in a while and I worry it is no longer supported/updated and therefore it will eventually stop working.

What I would like to do it try to capture the data between the app and the device and reverse engineer the API so write my own app.

I can see that the device has port 8080 open so I am hoping that it is a HTTP based API but on a non standard port.

Ive looked and both Fiddler and Postman but cant quite seem to work out whether their proxy will capture the data from from port 8080 or just 80/443.

Any thoughts how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: shouldn't you use packet capture tools like wireshark for this task?

Comment: I think that's what explained here: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/capturing-http-requests/#using-postmans-proxy-example
I would just give it a try.

Comment: Will using postman work if the data isnt on port 80/443 though?

Comment: Set in iOS Wifi settings your PC as proxy (IP of your PC in your local LAN) plus port 8888. In Fiddler enable "allow remote computers to connect" in connection settings.